# What are the best method's to check/test patches on site?

Tags: testing, magento-1.4, tests, security-patch

I have applied changes for following patches

```
SUPEE-10975
SUPEE-11086
SUPEE-11155
SUPEE-11219
SUPEE-11295
SUPEE-11314
```

For magento 1 website.

Please let me know what are the **best method's to check/test patches on site**.
(Automatic & manual)

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?